# Is there a way to detect the presence of hardware acceleration on Safari, or WebKit?

Tags: safari, webkit, hardware-acceleration

We have a custom WebKit app that, on Windows, uses a WebKit build, and on Mac, uses the OS's webview component. We're looking for a way to tell whether or not we're taking advantage of hardware acceleration.

Are there any relevant settings, e.g. in a plist? It seems likely we forgot a compile flag, or to set some option in the webview initialization, or something like that.

Alternately, if there were a flag for turning it off or on in Safari, then (for Mac at least) we could run benchmarks with and without in Safari, then compare the results in our app.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to custom apps, or OS-specific webkit builds, but in Safari, GPU is activated automatically when using 3D transform methods with the `-webkit-transform` css property.

`translateZ(npx)` becomes `translate3d(0px, 0px, npx)`
`rotateY(ndeg)` becomes `rotate3d(0, 1, 0, ndeg)`
`scaleZ(n)` becomes `scale3d(0, 0, n)`

I'm unsure of how to explicitly check for the existence of acceleration, but testing both methods in Safari on an old iPhone 3G resulted in varied performance.

Comment: Hmmm... in modern Safari (i.e. not on old iPhones), is the GPU *not* activated when doing 2D methods? If so that could become a test, by comparing the speed of the two methods: if they are the same, then no hardware acceleration is available.